# Why do we use inner classes?

Tags: java, inner-classes

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Java (anonymous or not) inner classes: is it good to use them ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284396/java-anonymous-or-not-inner-classes-is-it-good-to-use-them)
>   [Why we use inner classes ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707724/why-we-use-inner-classes)

Why do we use inner classes in java?

Comment: See this http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-03/02-qa-innerclass.html

Comment: @razlebe: Thanks for the link. before posting the question here i searched in stackoverflow but i couldnt find it. So, i posted the question.